# Is this function to erase a linked list correct?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Using the following struct:

```
typedef struct lista {
    int num;
    struct lista * sig;
} nodo;
```

We then have the following function to erase a linked list formed by the previous struct nodes:

```
void eliminarListaEntera(nodo * registro) {
    nodo * aux = NULL;
    
    while(registro->sig != NULL){
        aux=registro->sig;
        printf("Borrando nodo de la lista\n");
        free(registro);
        registro=aux;
    }
    free(registro);
    registro = NULL;
}
```

The issue I'm seeing: If I run the following inside main() before and after calling eliminarListaEntera:

```
printf("POINTER %p\n", (void *) primerNodo);
```

I get the same value. Shouldn't it be 0 (NULL) after calling the delete function?

If I try to traverse it again, I get only a random value like -159426562 which I guess it's because it's retrieving a garbage value from memory.

Comment: The `free()` function cannot set the pointer to NULL.

Comment: I see. I mean...I was expecting to get a 0 or NULL when running that printf function after deleting the list (Given the fact that I even set the pointer to NULL right before finishing the function) but that was not the case. Just to check: If I print "Pointer", it's the address it's pointing to. "&Pointer" would be the address in memory of that pointer and "*pointer" would de-reference that pointer and retrieve the value it points to, correct? Hence why I expected a 0...

Comment: You would have to pass a pointer to a pointer into your function to be able to alter the value in the calling function.  That’s why `free()` can’t set the pointer to NULL too.  The last line of your function does nothing useful.

Comment: You only pass a copy of `primerNodo` into that function. The real variable `primerNodo` cannot be modified from inside that function. Besides that: You are not supposed to even know what value you would find at that address because you are not allowed to access that memory again after you have passed that address to `free`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Whether `free` can set the pointer to `NULL` is irrelevant. The `eliminarListaEntera` routine sets `registro` to `NULL`, and the question is about why the pointer in `main` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `main` calls `eliminarListaEntera(primerNodo)`, it passes the value of `primerNodo`. Inside `eliminarListaEntera`, the parameter `registro` is a separate object and does not refer in any way to the `primerNodo` in `main`.

The statement `registro = NULL;` sets `registro` to `NULL` and has no effect on `primerNodo` in `main`.

If you want a called function to affect an object in the caller, you can pass a pointer to the object:

```
void eliminarListaEntera(nodo **p) {
    nodo *registro = *p;  // Copy the original pointer for ease of use.
    nodo * aux = NULL;
    
    while(registro->sig != NULL){
        aux=registro->sig;
        printf("Borrando nodo de la lista\n");
        free(registro);
        registro=aux;
    }
    free(registro);
    *p = NULL;  // Set the original pointer to NULL.
}
```

Then `main` can call this routine with `eliminarListaEntera(&primerNodo);`.

Comment: Ahhh! That explains it then. But hold on...I saw the other comments...So I need to do something like eliminarListaEntera(nodo ** registro)?? Only then would I able to set it to NULL inside the function?

Comment: @4d4143: I updated with a method to change the pointer in `main`.

Comment: Mmmm now I'm a little bit confused. Why the need to use &?

Comment: @4d4143: When used as an argument (or, generally, when used for its value in any expression), `x` is the value of `x`. `&x` is the address of `x`. To give a function a pointer to an object, you must provide its address, not its value.